# Как оценить приложение в Play-market

Tags: android

Создал в своем приложение функцию "оценить приложение". Вопрос состоит в том, как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог в моем приложение оценить его и эти данные пересылались в *play-market* и автоматически там стояла его оценка, понимаю что нужно как то через `Intent` и `Uri`, возможно даже проверка на то, чтоб пользователь был зарегистрирован в *play-market'e*, вообще, реально ли это сделать? Делал эту функцию в `AlertDialog`

**MainActivity.java**

```
final AlertDialog.Builder ratingdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
ratingdialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
ratingdialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icr);
ratingdialog.setTitle("Оценить приложение");
ratingdialog.setCancelable(false);
View linearlayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratingdialog, null);
ratingdialog.setView(linearlayout);

final RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)linearlayout.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);

rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {
                ratingBar.setRating(rating);
                ratingBar.setRating(rating);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "рейтинг: " + String.valueOf(rating),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

ratingdialog.setPositiveButton("Готово",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
ratingdialog.create();
ratingdialog.show();
```

Comment: "вообще реально ли это сделать ?" - ответ нет

Comment: @s_klepcha ну почему же нереально? Goggle ведь сделали! Поэтому мне кажется что реально но затраты и стоят цели!

Comment: Если бы такой способ был бы,  то его следовало бы отключить. Каждый девелопер мог бы накручивать себе рейтинг (и не только себе) как ему хочется. А это не нужно.

Comment: как тогда реализовать переход в play маркет чтоб оценить приложение?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application

Comment: подскажите как отправить сообщение на gmail чтоб вызывалась только именно это приложение gmail

Comment: @fcbarcafc если у вас остались нерешенные проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @zTrap http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633690/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-gmail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как подсказали в реализации в комментах что бы открыть гуглмаркет следует использовать такой код:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

На счёт автоматической оценки. Это реально. Но работы очень много. И не имеет смысла т.к. автоматическая оценка противоречит правилам гугла и гугл автоматически(я так думаю, нужно проверять) отлавливает такие приложения и удаляет.

Comment: Я к сожалению не понимаю как оценивая приложение переходить в плэймаркет, что бы поставить звёзды