# Отправка сообщения на gmail

Tags: android, sendmail

Подскажите как отправить сообщение на gmail чтоб вызывалась только именно это приложение gmail

```
public class EmailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    AppCompatButton send;
    EditText address,emailtext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.emailactivity);
        send = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                    Uri address = Uri.parse("");
                    Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
                    startActivity(surf);
                }
        });

        send = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.send:
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                // Кому
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {"******@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, address.getText().toString());
                // О чём
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailtext.getText().toString());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Отправка письма"));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

При отправке выходит много программ спомощью которых можно отправить, как сделать чтобы была именно только gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод для отправки письма:

```
private void sendUsingGmail(Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo == null) continue;
            if ("com.google.android.gm".equals(info.activityInfo.packageName)){
                intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Отправка письма"));
}
```

Использование:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {"******@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, address.getText().toString());
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailtext.getText().toString());
sendUsingGmail(emailIntent);
```

Пояснение:

Этот метод ищет в установленных приложениях приложение с пакетом `com.google.android.gm`, который соответствует пакету приложения Gmail. При нахождении использует приложение Gmail, при отсутствии создает стандартный выбор приложения для отправки письма.